# $state.go don't work in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating a cordova app with ionic framework, i created a blank app with CLI, in my  index.html i have a slide box, in which i have a button in the last slide.
I have registered a click event in that button, in click in the button i would like to navigate to templates/projects.html.
I hope my problem is clear.
Thanks

**index.html** file

```
  <body ng-app="starter" class="platform-android platform-cordova platform-webview">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">BabyLapse</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
      <ion-slide-box style="height:100%" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
          <ion-slide >
              <div style="height:100%" class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1>
                  <img src="img/tutorial_img1.jpg">
              </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
              <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1>
              <img src="img/tutorial_img2.jpg">
              </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
              <div class="box pink"><h1>PINK</h1>
                  <img src="img/tutorial_img3.jpg" class="image">
              </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
              <div class="box blue"><h1>BLUE</h1>
                  <img src="img/tutorial_img4.jpg">
              </div>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide ng-controller="FirstSlideCtrl">
              <div class="box yellow"><h1>YELLOW</h1>
                 <!-- <img src="img/tutorial_img5.jpg" >-->
                  <button style="z-index:1000;height:100px;width:100px" ng-click="go('app.projects');">Créer Projet</button>
              </div>
          </ion-slide>
      </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

**app.js** file

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngCordova'])
      .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
          $stateProvider

              .state('app', {
              url: "/app",
              abstract: true,
              templateUrl: "index.html",
              controller: 'StarterCtrl'

          })

          .state('app.projects', {
              url: "/projects",
              views: {
                  'projects': {
                      templateUrl: "templates/projects.html",
                      controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
                  }
              }
          });
          //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/projects');
      })

  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
          // for form inputs)
          if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          }
          if (window.StatusBar) {
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
          }

      })
  });
```

**controllers.js**

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ui.router'])

   .controller("StarterCtrl", function($scope) {
           $scope.data = {
               numViewableSlides: 0,
               slideIndex: 0,
               initialInstruction: true,
               secondInstruction: false

           };
           $scope.slideHasChanged = function(index) {
               $scope.data.slideIndex = index;
           };
           $scope.go = function(route) {
               alert('1');
               $state.go(route);

           };

       })
       .controller("ProjectsCtrl", function($scope) {

           $scope.playlists = [{
               title: 'Reggae',
               id: 1
           }, {
               title: 'Chill',
               id: 2
           }, {
               title: 'Dubstep',
               id: 3
           }, {
               title: 'Indie',
               id: 4
           }, {
               title: 'Rap',
               id: 5
           }, {
               title: 'Cowbell',
               id: 6
           }];
       })
       .controller("FirstSlideCtrl", function($scope, $state) {

           $scope.go = function(route) {
               alert(route);
               $state.go('app.projects');

           };

       });
```

Comment: where is your `<ion-view>` element that the template should be loaded into?

Comment: i have not an <ion-view> tag in my index.html, i edited my post with a complete index.html body, should i have one?

Comment: yes, you need an outlet for the template to be written to, so you definitely have to have something, `ion-view` or `ion-content`... http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Comment: i added a <ion-view> element but the problem is not solved

Comment: What error are you receiving in your console?

Comment: @YuujinLee no errors, "only Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"

Comment: In your state for app.projects, can you try to remove the slash in /projects?  So url : 'projects'.  If this doesn't work, i'll try to recreate this if i have time and help

Comment: i did it, but the problem persist

Comment: If you can put your code in a plunker or jsfiddle I can help investigate

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is the code in codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVLaje, the last slide contains the button which doesn't work

Comment: @tarekfellah: Feel free to accept some of the answers to your questions. That's how S.O. works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot follow your code so I'll try to recreate.
In Ionic/Cordova you should have an **index.html** which would be your entry for the application.

This is the place where you bind your HTML with the angular app and where your reference your scripts.

It should have a body with the main nav-view `<ion-nav-view>`:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>  

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

My `ng-app` is called **app** but you can easily replace it with **starter**.

Then you would have separate "pages" for different views. I can imagine in your situation you would have one view for the slider and the second one for the project's creation.

Each view must be defined in a `<ion-view>` where you're going to a have a content `<ion-content>`.

I imagine you're going to need to states:

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'mainController',
})

.state('projects', {
    url: '/projects',
    templateUrl: 'projects.html',
    controller: 'projectsController',
});
```

if you want to go to projects from the slider page you simply have to:

```
$state.go('projects')
```

This is the end [result](http://plnkr.co/edit/u76xPCOQBa1mNGYj8N4l?p=preview) in a plunker.

As you can see I got read of the abstract view cause it seems to me that you don't really need it as you're not using any base template: side-menu or tabs.

You can always add it but your abstract should never refer the index.html file.

Comment: It should now. Let me know if you have problems. Cheers.

Comment: i think that my problem was that i created a view route for index.html, i transfered the  slider code in a new view file and now the navigation works, thanks!